# nginx - connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, centos

Can't figure out why I keep getting 502 bad gateway nginx error.

Here is the error from nginx error log.

```
2012/12/03 19:30:21 [error] 20650#0: *939328 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 70.94.18.35, server: demo.domain.com, request: "GET /assets/js/msgFBmodal.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://108.166.94.94:7080/assets/js/msgFBmodal.js", host: "demo.domain.com", referrer: "http://demo.domain.com/register/user_profile"
```

I'm on a rackspace cloud sever, CentOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit the same problem, in my case, it was the firewall port which needed to be opened.

Please check your firewall / a firewall ahead of your machine that could be refusing the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your upstream address works correct (in your case 108.166.94.94:7080/assets/js/msgFBmodal.js). If everything fine then try to see packets from nginx to upstream for example like this

```
sudo ngrep -q -d eth0 -W byline port 7080
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem, it was because i didn't install php on my nginx server

By installing php-fpm this problem was totally solved.
 it is just the same thing as php fastcgi but with lots of configuration options and advantages

you can know more about php-fpm form [here](http://php-fpm.org/)!

or You can follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524373/nginx-connect-failed-111-connection-refused-while-connecting-to-upstream)!

Comment: you can do your settings by seeing this link <http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-install-configure-nginx-php5/>

Answer (score 0):

I was following a tutorial on uwsgi and nginx and I kept having this same message and failure, but my problem was because the initial starting directory that I thought was set  was not due to a no longer working config option, and my unix socket was being put (or attempted to put) in / directory. When I put the full path for my socket in the .ini config file it worked fine. yeeeargh that's a night I'll never get back :D

like this
[uwsgi]
....
socket = /var/www/stage/deeznts.sock