# nginx: connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, mod-fastcgi, http-status-code-502

Trying to deploy my first portal .

I am getting 502 gateway timeout error in browser when i was sending the request through browser

when i checked the logs , i got this error

```
 2014/02/03 09:00:32 [error] 16607#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 14.159.131.19, server: foo.com, request: "GET HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "22.11.180.154"
```

is there any problem related to permissions

Comment: please add info to help understand the problem, your config, what you did? what links are broken, and if any work or not, etc

Comment: my problem was solved .... i havent installed php in my server

Comment: See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852884/nginx-connect-failed-error

Comment: @lucky So I think it's better to close this question.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I don't think that solution would work anyways because you will see some error message in your error log file.

The solution was a lot easier than what I thought.

simply, open the following path to your php5-fpm

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

or if you're the admin 'root'

```
nano /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

Then find this line and uncomment it:

```
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
```

This solution will make you be able to use **listen = 127.0.0.1:9000** in your vhost blocks

like this: **fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;**

after you make the modifications, all you need is to restart or reload both Nginx and Php5-fpm

**Php5-fpm**

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

or

```
sudo service php5-fpm reload
```

**Nginx**

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

or

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

From the comments:

Also comment

```
;listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

and add

```
listen = 9000
```

Comment: `listen = 9000` and `;listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`

Comment: On CentOS 7 this file was at `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` for me and I had to add `listen = 9000` and comment out `listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock`.

Comment: Why not change the NGINX config to use sockets instead of localhost:9000? By changing the `fastcgi_pass` line to "`astcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I wrote two upstreams in NGINX conf

```
upstream php_upstream {
    server unix:/var/run/php/my.site.sock;
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

...

fastcgi_pass php_upstream;
```

but in `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` I listened the socket only

```
listen = /var/run/php/my.site.sock
```

So I need just socket, no any `127.0.0.1:9000`, and I just removed IP+port upstream

```
upstream php_upstream {
    server unix:/var/run/php/my.site.sock;
}
```

This could be rewritten without an upstream

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/my.site.sock;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful for someone:

If you have multiple versions of PHP installed e.g 8.0 and 7.4 on your mac, and you have tried several options and still gets a 502 Gateway error, trying check how your valet connects with your PHP version and Nginx.

from terminal run `valet use php@7.4` if that's the version you use.
The current version will be unlinked and the new version linked then Nginx and php@7.4 will be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in `Centos 8`.
In this file `/etc/nginx/default.d/php.conf` I just replaced the below line, and it works perfectly.

```
#orignal line
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

#replaced with
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
```